# tensorflow new API: TensorRT create_inference_graph error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have a self defined Faster R-CNN network for object detection, in which I define some self-defined operators: `nms` and `roi_pooling` which is compiled to `.so` file. The `.so` file is wrapped which can be called by tensorflow framework.

After I convert tensorflow frozen graph to `.pb` file, I use the following code:

```
trt_graph = trt.create_inference_graph(graph_def, OUTPUT_NAMES,
                                         max_batch_size=cfg.test_batch_per_gpu,
                                         max_workspace_size_bytes=5000000000,
                                         precision_mode="FP16")  # Get optimized graph
```

But it report a lot of warning and error:

```
2018-04-25 23:45:54.451261: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:0 due to: "Invalid argument: Failed to create Input layer" SKIPPING......( 30 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.452898: E tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/log/trt_logger.cc:38] DefaultLogger Parameter check failed at: ../builder/Network.cpp::addInput::377, condition: isValidDims(dims)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.452914: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:1 due to: "Invalid argument: Failed to create Input layer" SKIPPING......( 23 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.455730: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:2 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/Exp" SKIPPING......( 9 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.457270: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:3 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/Exp_1" SKIPPING......( 9 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.458798: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:4 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/Exp_5" SKIPPING......( 9 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.460327: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:5 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 1 resnet_v1_50_5/strided_slice_60" SKIPPING......( 6 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.461882: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:6 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/Exp_6" SKIPPING......( 9 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.463425: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:7 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 1 resnet_v1_50_5/strided_slice_6" SKIPPING......( 6 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.464976: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:8 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/ones_2" SKIPPING......( 4 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.466543: E tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/log/trt_logger.cc:38] DefaultLogger Parameter check failed at: ../builder/Network.cpp::addInput::377, condition: isValidDims(dims)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.466571: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:9 due to: "Invalid argument: Failed to create Input layer" SKIPPING......( 33 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.468105: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:10 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/ones_1" SKIPPING......( 3 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.469726: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:11 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/Exp_7" SKIPPING......( 9 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.471356: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:12 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 2 resnet_v1_50_5/ones_3" SKIPPING......( 4 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.473207: E tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/log/trt_logger.cc:38] DefaultLogger Parameter check failed at: ../builder/Network.cpp::addInput::377, condition: isValidDims(dims)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.473259: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:13 due to: "Invalid argument: Failed to create Input layer" SKIPPING......( 380 nodes)
2018-04-25 23:45:54.475765: W tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:418] subgraph conversion error for subgraph_index:14 due to: "Unimplemented: Require 4 dimensional input. Got 1 resnet_v1_50_5/strided_slice_8" SKIPPING......( 6 nodes)
...
```

What is the reason of this error? How to address it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @DaveS may be the TensorRT only support 4D tensor on some particular layers. I guess

Comment: I'm getting similar errors while trying to convert a resnet based pyramid network.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to TensorRT requiring sizes of all tensors being known when it's called upon to optimize the graph.  One possible fix could be specifying a fixed input image tensor size for your faster rcnn model by, say, making the following modification to the model config file.

Originally:

```
faster_rcnn {
  num_classes: 90
  image_resizer {
    keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
      min_dimension: 600
      max_dimension: 1024
    }
  }
  ......
```

Modified:

```
faster_rcnn {
  num_classes: 90
  image_resizer {
    fixed_shape_resizer {
      height: 600
      width:  1024
    }
  }
  ......
```

Reference: https://github.com/NVIDIA-Jetson/tf_trt_models/issues/6#issuecomment-423098067

Answer (score -1):

This happens when your input node is not registered correctly, make sure you are using the correct input node names, you can print the names of nodes from tf graph from within a session as `print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])` For details refer to nvidia developer forums, https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032314/?comment=5251907

Comment: A [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).